# How to add visuals and mouse interactions to grid boxes

Tags: javascript, css

I am a beginner and picked a selfmade RPG talent calculator as my first project. I am seemingly stuck and dont know how to proceed.

So i have figured out how to add background pictures, talent pictures and even how to have only those shown that actually have assigned pictures. I also have a bit of js code that adds an unlocked class to the talent-boxes in the grid and make them colored from a basic greyscale.

What i am failing at is adding a counter in the bottom right corner of the talent-box in the grid that displays how many points are assigned. I dont have the code actually written yet that provides mouseclick context but i would like to at least figure out how to add a small box in the corner that says (0) which will later be changed by js code.

Example how it should end up working see here: https://wotlk.evowow.com/?talent#h

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Talent Calculator</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <div class="talent-calculator">
    <div class="talent-tree" style="background-image: url(images/tree1.jpg);">
      <div class="talent-grid">
        <!-- Talent Tree 1 -->
        <!-- Tier 1 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010104</div>
        <!-- Tier 2 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010201</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010202</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010203</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010204</div>
        <!-- Tier 3 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010301</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010302</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010303</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010304</div>
        <!-- Tier 4 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010401</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010402</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010403</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010404</div>
        <!-- Tier 5 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010501</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010502</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010503</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010504</div>
        <!-- Tier 6 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010601</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010602</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010603</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010604</div>
        <!-- Tier 7 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010701</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010702</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010703</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010704</div>
        <!-- Tier 8 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010801</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010802</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010803</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010804</div>
        <!-- Tier 9 -->
        <div class="talent-box">010901</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010902</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010903</div>
        <div class="talent-box">010904</div>
        <!-- Tier 10 -->
        <div class="talent-box">011001</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011002</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011003</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011004</div>
        <!-- Tier 11 -->
        <div class="talent-box">011101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">011104</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="talent-tree" style="background-image: url(images/tree2.jpg);">
      <div class="talent-grid">
        <!-- Talent Tree 2 -->
        <!-- Tier 1 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020104</div>
        <!-- Tier 2 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020201</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020202</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020203</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020204</div>
        <!-- Tier 3 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020301</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020302</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020303</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020304</div>
        <!-- Tier 4 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020401</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020402</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020403</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020404</div>
        <!-- Tier 5 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020501</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020502</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020503</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020504</div>
        <!-- Tier 6 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020601</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020602</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020603</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020604</div>
        <!-- Tier 7 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020701</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020702</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020703</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020704</div>
        <!-- Tier 8 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020801</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020802</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020803</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020804</div>
        <!-- Tier 9 -->
        <div class="talent-box">020901</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020902</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020903</div>
        <div class="talent-box">020904</div>
        <!-- Tier 10 -->
        <div class="talent-box">021001</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021002</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021003</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021004</div>
        <!-- Tier 11 -->
        <div class="talent-box">021101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">021104</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="talent-tree" style="background-image: url(images/tree3.jpg);">
      <div class="talent-grid">
        <!-- Talent Tree 3 -->
        <!-- Tier 1 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030104</div>
        <!-- Tier 2 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030201</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030202</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030203</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030204</div>
        <!-- Tier 3 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030301</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030302</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030303</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030304</div>
        <!-- Tier 4 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030401</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030402</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030403</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030404</div>
        <!-- Tier 5 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030501</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030502</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030503</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030504</div>
        <!-- Tier 6 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030601</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030602</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030603</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030604</div>
        <!-- Tier 7 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030701</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030702</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030703</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030704</div>
        <!-- Tier 8 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030801</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030802</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030803</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030804</div>
        <!-- Tier 9 -->
        <div class="talent-box">030901</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030902</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030903</div>
        <div class="talent-box">030904</div>
        <!-- Tier 10 -->
        <div class="talent-box">031001</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031002</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031003</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031004</div>
        <!-- Tier 11 -->
        <div class="talent-box">031101</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031102</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031103</div>
        <div class="talent-box">031104</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


.talent-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 6; /* Increase the z-index value */
  border: 2px solid #888; /* Grey border */
  border-radius: 6px; /* Corner radius */
}

.talent-box.unlocked .talent-image {
  filter: none;
  border-color: #00ff00; /* Green border */
}
```

EDIT: the .talent-image and .unlocked are added by js

Comment: Any ideas? I am pretty stuck here

Answer (score -1):

Do not know exactly how you designed your elements but this type of display can be achieved using relatively positioned wrapper (e.g. wrapper of your `.talent-image`) and absolutely positioned inner element (e.g. points counter in your case). It would look like this in HTML:

```
<div class="talent-image">
    <div class="points-counter">1</div>
</div>
```

And this is CSS:

```
.talent-image {
    position: relative;
}

.talent-image .points-counter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

It's super simplified, adjust it to your needs. `position: relative` tells child elements with absolute positioning to calculate their position based on this parent element. Then in child we position it in bottom right corner.

Comment: Edited main post for better understanding. Do you need the js code too?